# sp_prepare vs sp_execeute PHP MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

This question is regarding the PDO_SQLSVR driver for PHP and Microsoft SQL Server and how it interacts with the database, whether via `sp_prepare` (prepare statement execution) or `sp_execute` (direct statement  execute).

By default the driver uses `sp_prepare` but swapped it out after reading the [Why sp_prepare Isn’t as “Good” as sp_executesql for Performance](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/03/sp_prepare-isnt-good-sp_executesql-performance/) post on Brent Ozar's blog by Erik Darling, which states that `sp_execute` is a better choice for reasons listed in the article.

However, this conflicts with [Microsoft's recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/direct-statement-execution-prepared-statement-execution-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) of `sp_prepare` being better.

Does anyone have experience with either and maybe have some recommendations what approach worked better for them?

Comment: sp_prepare does optimize the statements, but the details matter.  As Darling's post says, it optimizes it for mediocre, which may be best case, depending on your data skew.  If your queries are all single row kinds of stuff, it won't matter either way.  Otherwise it depends on your data skew and what you want to optimize for (the general case or the specific case).

Comment: @JonathanFite thanks, query results sets are mixed in terms of rows and this is a somewhat busy system ~4000 batchrequests/sec. Would be great to load test with both options but realistically don't think this is an option